# Ajax request is not sending data over POST

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got the following Javascript function

```
http_post = function (url, data, success) {
    var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);

    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: json_data,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: success,
        fail: function(sender, message, details) {
            console.log(sender, message, details);
        }
    });
}
```

Which I am calling like this

```
$('#teammate_search_input').keyup(delay(function (e) {
    var value = $(this).val();

    http_post("{{ \Path::href('roster', 'search_name') }}", {name: value}, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });

}, 500));
```

Which is hitting this PHP script

```
if(!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $download = $this->model('download');
    $results = $download->search_teammate($_POST['name']);
    echo json_encode(['term' => $_POST['name'], 'results' => $results]);
}
```

Which is supposed to simply pull a list of users with a name that matches the input. This is all working fine (I get the response I am expecting), except the `term` is always set to `null`, so it returns a list of *all* users.

Result:

```
{term: null, results: Array(5)}
```

It appears as though the data is not being sent over the request.

Things I've tried:

- Changed `{name: value}` to `{name: 'test'}` (2nd param of function call)
- Removed the `var json_data` line and replaced `data: json_data,` with `data: data`

Why is my data not being sent over the request?

Comment: JSON in PHP is not put on the $_GET or $_POST.  You have to read it from the request yourself

Comment: Is your PHP endpoint configured to accept JSON? I don't believe this is the case by default (assuming you're not using a server-side library or framework). Try just send form-urlencoded data; ie. remove `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` and use `data: data` without calling `JSON.stringify()` on it

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866571/receive-json-post-with-php

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That worked, thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. I added it as an answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your PHP endpoint configured to accept JSON? I don't believe this is the case by default (assuming you're not using a server-side library or framework).

You can instead send form-urlencoded data. To do that remove `contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",` and use `data: data` without calling `JSON.stringify()` on it, like this:

```js
let http_post = function(url, data, success) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
    success: success,
    fail: function(sender, message, details) {
      console.log(sender, message, details);
    }
  });
}
```

Note that this makes your function almost entirely redundant, but I left it in anyway.